# Why does the If condition never executes?

Tags: php

I have written a simple  script and a part of that script does not executes

**This is the part that isnt woriking:**

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($inFile)) !== FALSE) 

{
    if(($line[0] === "$fin") )
    {
        echo ("$asd is 5");
        $line = explode (",", "$tempstr10"); 
        $asd=$asd+1;

    } 
    fputcsv($outFile, $line );
}
```

More specifically the if statement's body isnt being executed.

this block of code is supposed to do this:
it checks if $line[0] === "$fin" ($fin has a value) meaning if value of $fin is found inside of $line[0] then execute this

```
    {
        echo ("$asd is 5");
        $line = explode (",", "$tempstr10"); 
        $asd=$asd+1;

    }
```

but it seems like even if the value of $fin is similar to the value inside of $line[0] its not executing the body of the if statement

What am i doing wrong here ?

**UPDATE :**

These are the values stored in the csv file :

```
"1234  "," 1234-12-31  " 
"12345  "," 1234-12-31  " 
"123456  "," 1234-12-31  "
```

**This is the result of var_dump :**

```
string(4) "1234" string(4) "1234" string(4) "1234" string(4) "1234" string(4) "1234"
```

Comment: WHat is the value of `$fin`

Comment: Remember `===` checks type as well as equality! You are wrapping `$fin` in `""` and therefore making it into a String.

Comment: @RiggsFolly value of $fin is 12345
and yes i have tried : `===` with `""` and without `""` , i also tried `==` but nothing seem to work

Comment: Post the input file (just the necessary part of it if it's too large.

Comment: Also do a var_dump of $fin and $line[0] before the if

Comment: @EliasSoares i have updated the OP with the var_dump results and the values stored in the csv file

Comment: The value in the file has spaces after the number `"1234  "`, so may be worth trying to trim the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your csv have trailing whitespaces. You must trim the input to compare:

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($inFile)) !== FALSE) 

{
    if((trim($line[0]) === "$fin") )
    {
        echo ("$asd is 5");
        $line = explode (",", "$tempstr10"); 
        $asd=$asd+1;

    } 
    fputcsv($outFile, $line );
}
```